# `jupyter notebook` gives error: `"Could not open static file ''"` on macOS

Tags: jupyter-notebook, upgrade, conda

I haven't changed my system configuration, But I'm spotting this error for the first time today.

I've reported it here: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4871

```
> jupyter notebook
[I 10:44:20.102 NotebookApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from /usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterlab
[I 10:44:20.102 NotebookApp] JupyterLab application directory is /usr/local/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab
[I 10:44:20.104 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /Users/pi
[I 10:44:20.104 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 10:44:20.104 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=586797fb9049c0faea24f2583c4de32c08d45c89051fb07d
[I 10:44:20.104 NotebookApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=586797fb9049c0faea24f2583c4de32c08d45c89051fb07d
[I 10:44:20.104 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 10:44:20.110 NotebookApp]

    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///Users/pi/Library/Jupyter/runtime/nbserver-65385-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=586797fb9049c0faea24f2583c4de32c08d45c89051fb07d
     or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=586797fb9049c0faea24f2583c4de32c08d45c89051fb07d
[E 10:44:21.457 NotebookApp] Could not open static file ''
[W 10:44:21.512 NotebookApp] 404 GET /static/components/react/react-dom.production.min.js (::1) 9.02ms referer=http://localhost:8888/tree?token=BLA
[W 10:44:21.548 NotebookApp] 404 GET /static/components/react/react-dom.production.min.js (::1) 0.99ms referer=http://localhost:8888/tree?token=BLA
Set
```

Looks like this issue was fixed in `Jupyter 6.0.1`

So the question becomes: can I force-install `jupyter 6.0.1`?

As the initial question has now provoked a second question, I now ask this new question here: [How to force `conda` to install the latest version of `jupyter`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57843733/how-to-force-conda-to-install-the-latest-version-of-jupyter)

Alternatively I can manually provide the missing file, but I'm not sure *where*. I've asked here: [Where does Jupyter install site-packages on macOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57843888/where-does-jupyter-install-site-packages-on-macos)

## Research:

https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/pull/4772 *"add missing react-dom js to package data #4772"* on 6 Aug 2019

> minrk added this to the 6.0.1 milestone on 18 Jul

Ok, so can I get Jupyter Notebook 6.0.1?

`brew cask install anaconda` downloads `~/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/{LONG HEX}--Anaconda3-2019.07-MacOSX-x86_64` which is July, and `conda --version` reports `conda 4.7.10`.  But this is for `Anaconda` which is the Package *Manager*.

```
> conda list | grep jupy
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py37_7
jupyter_client            5.3.1                      py_0
jupyter_console           6.0.0                    py37_0
jupyter_core              4.5.0                      py_0
jupyterlab                1.0.2            py37hf63ae98_0
jupyterlab_server         1.0.0                      py_0
```

So that's a bit confusing. No `jupyter notebook` here.

```
> which jupyter
/usr/local/anaconda3/bin/jupyter

> jupyter --version
jupyter core     : 4.5.0
jupyter-notebook : 6.0.0
qtconsole        : 4.5.1
ipython          : 7.6.1
ipykernel        : 5.1.1
jupyter client   : 5.3.1
jupyter lab      : 1.0.2
nbconvert        : 5.5.0
ipywidgets       : 7.5.0
nbformat         : 4.4.0
traitlets        : 4.3.2
```

Ok, so it appears `jupyter-notebook` is in `jupyter` which is maintained by Anaconda.

Can we update this?

https://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/projects/upgrade-notebook.html

```
> conda update jupyter
 :
```

Alas `jupyter --version` is still `6.0.0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed this by updating both jupyter on pip and pip3 (just to be safe) and this fixed the problem

using both

> `pip install --upgrade jupyter`

and

> `pip3 install --upgrade jupyter --no-cache-dir`

I believe you can do this in the terminal as well as in conda's terminal (since conda envs also have pip)

Answer (score 1):

As per [Where does Jupyter install site-packages on macOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57843888/where-does-jupyter-install-site-packages-on-macos), I locate where on my system `jupyter`  is searching for this missing file:

```
> find / -path '*/static/components'  2>/dev/null
/usr/local/anaconda3/pkgs/notebook-6.0.0-py37_0/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/static/components
/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/static/components
```

And as per https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/pull/4772#issuecomment-515794823, if I download that file and deposit it in the second location, i.e. creating:

```
/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/static/components/react/react-dom.production.min.js
```

... now `jupyter notebook` launches without errors.

(*NOTE: Being cautious I have also copied it into the first location. But that doesn't seem to have any effect.*)