# How to force `conda` to install the latest version of `jupyter`?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, upgrade, conda

This question is motivated by [`jupyter notebook` gives error: `"Could not open static file ''"` on macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57843695/jupyter-notebook-gives-error-could-not-open-static-file-on-macos)

After `conda update jupyter`, `jupyter --version` gives `jupyter-notebook : 6.0.0`

However on https://github.com/jupyter/notebook, clicking `Branch: master -> tags` I see a `6.0.1` tag.

How can I upgrade to `6.0.1`?

```
> conda install jupyter=6.0.1
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - jupyter=6.0.1

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

I can't see any candidates on https://anaconda.org

Is this a dead-end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, note that the actual package you want to upgrade/install is `notebook`, not `jupyter`. The Anaconda channel hasn't released that version of `notebook` yet. [Conda Forge has it](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/notebook/files), so you can get it with

```
conda install -c conda-forge notebook
```

However, just be aware that compatibility between Conda Forge and Anaconda package builds is not guaranteed. Best practice is to create a new env that prioritizes Conda Forge from the start:

```
conda create -n my_jupyter_env -c conda-forge jupyter
```

Generally it isn't a good idea to mess with **base** env, and if you want something other than a default Anaconda install, I recommend starting with Miniconda and leaving **base** alone (other than the occasional `conda upgrade conda`).