# Where does Jupyter install site-packages on macOS?

Tags: macos, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Due to a bug in the current shipping Jupyter (`6.0.0`), I get a missing file error.

It can't find `/static/components/react/react-dom.production.min.js`

https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/pull/4772#issuecomment-515794823 advises to manually add the file.

However I cannot locate the absolute path, So I don't know *where* to put the file.

Where is `/static/...` located on my filesystem?

Full output:

```
> jupyter notebook
[I 10:44:20.102 NotebookApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from /usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterlab
[I 10:44:20.102 NotebookApp] JupyterLab application directory is /usr/local/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab
[I 10:44:20.104 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /Users/pi
[I 10:44:20.104 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 10:44:20.104 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=586797fb9049c0faea24f2583c4de32c08d45c89051fb07d
[I 10:44:20.104 NotebookApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=586797fb9049c0faea24f2583c4de32c08d45c89051fb07d
[I 10:44:20.104 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 10:44:20.110 NotebookApp]

    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///Users/pi/Library/Jupyter/runtime/nbserver-65385-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=586797fb9049c0faea24f2583c4de32c08d45c89051fb07d
     or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=586797fb9049c0faea24f2583c4de32c08d45c89051fb07d
[E 10:44:21.457 NotebookApp] Could not open static file ''
[W 10:44:21.512 NotebookApp] 404 GET /static/components/react/react-dom.production.min.js (::1) 9.02ms referer=http://localhost:8888/tree?token=BLA
[W 10:44:21.548 NotebookApp] 404 GET /static/components/react/react-dom.production.min.js (::1) 0.99ms referer=http://localhost:8888/tree?token=BLA
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find / -path '*/static/components'  2>/dev/null
```

gets it:

```
/usr/local/anaconda3/pkgs/notebook-6.0.0-py37_0/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/static/components
/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/static/components
```

The `2>/dev/null` part is to stifle warning-lines such as "Permission denied" and "Operation not permitted". It redirects STDERR to /dev/null.